# Empty top line spacing in the text file

Tags: php, text, download, kohana, fwrite

I'm trying to generate and download a text file via Kohana framework, but it's adding a empty top line and tab indentation for the second line starting with content. here is my code:

```
<?php
class Controller_Add extends Controller_Siteadmin 
{
    public function __construct(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        parent::__construct($request, $response);   
    }
    public function action_sample()
    {
        $content ="hello this is sample text file";
        $filename = "yourfile.txt";
        $f = fopen($filename, 'w');
        fwrite($f, $content);
        fclose($f);
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        readfile($filename);
    }
}
?>
```

And the OUTPUT:

[image]

The problem is not there if I create a dedicated PHP file, the problem only comes when I tried this with the Kohana framework 3.2.2.

FYI: I even removed all spacing in the index.php, database.php and bootstrap.php

What I need is without the empty top line and the second line indentation, could anyone help me to overcome this problem?

Comment: Did you try with `Content-Type: text/plain`?

Comment: just did, but no luck.

Comment: Do you have any white space after a closing `?>` tag or before an opening `<?php` tag? Any tab character or newline character would be included in the generated output.

Comment: I did tried both the scenarios that putting the ?> closing and removing it  but, no difference. In the top also I did few tests, removing all spaces.

Comment: Could it be that there are such white space in the included library (Kohana)?

Answer (score 1):

For such purposes Kohana has [`send_file`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Response#send_file) method in `Response` object.

This method is avaliable from `$this->response` property of `Controller` object like:

```
$this->response->send_file();
```

I your case to download generated content as text file you can use followind code within `Controller`:

```
$this->response
    ->body('hello this is sample text file')
    ->send_file(true, 'yourfile.txt');
```